# One-line instantiation of QVector with values without using <<

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, instantiation, variadic-functions

I can instantiate a QVector containing three QColor values with `QVector<QColor>() << x << y << z`.

Is it possible to instantiate it on one line without using the overloaded `<<`?   Something like `QVector<QColor>().addAll(x,y,z)`?

Comment: So you want to avoid two (negligible) function calls? Why? Is it some kind of bottleneck? Have you measured that this _is_ a bottleneck in that case? Or do you only dislike the use of the `<<` operator?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Because it's less typing.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I just wanted to know if there was a way to do it differently, for no great reason really.  Or maybe I just dislike the ```<<``` operator :)

Answer (score 4):

In C++11, you can use [`QVector`'s initializer list constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvector.html#QVector-5):

```
QVector<QColor>{x, y, z}
```

Comment: +1 For some reason I just assumed this was only brought in for Qt5.  Nice to be corrected!

Comment: Thanks.  But how about earlier C++ versions?

Comment: @neu242 I think your `<<` solution is the only option.